# How to use the variable in the setting of next javascript block in django template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I need to use the just inputed email, which I can get in Javascript, to define the email for the `<script>` code. How can I do that in a Django template?

```
    <script>
      function getRadioValue(id) {
      var radioBtn = document.getElementById(id);
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      // alert(email); //I get the email now.
      if (radioBtn.value == "1"){
        $("div[id^='div1']").hide();
      }
      if (radioBtn.value == "0"){
        $("div[id^='div1']").show();
      }
    }  
    </script>
    <div id="div1" style="display:none;">
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-description="Job Posting Fee ($25.00)"
        data-amount="2500"
        data-email= email     *****does not work.     
        > 
      </script> <!-- data-email = email -->
```

Comment: *"for the stripe script code. "* <- what do you mean here?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is Javascript-specific. What you want to do is to change the mail of the user in the script when he select a radio button.
So you just need to update the `date-email` attribute just after your `.show()` on the div. It'll update the script every time the user click on the radio button which is equal to *1*.

```
<script>
  function getRadioValue(id) {
      var radioBtn = document.getElementById(id);
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var myDiv = $("div[id^='div1']"); // Do some jQuery optimization by querying the node once.
      if (radioBtn.value == "1"){
          myDiv.hide();
      }
      else {
          myDiv.show();
          $("script", myDiv).attr('data-email', email); // <- update mail field here
      }
}  
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but it does work. still show "email" rather than user-input email in the popup form..

Comment: is this because javascript code in on section cannot change content of another script section?

Comment: @user3163033 If your javascript code and the `<script>` tag isn't in the same window (popup vs original window), it'll not work.

Comment: they are in the same window. this second <script> stripe block is shown as a pay button of stripe. when user click it, it pop up as a small window. but when I followed your suggestion, the email in the pop up windows did not get the update email in first script.

Comment: I hate to say that but... it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vPL4Y/ :-) In fact, I think you're messing with the selection of your input. Try to select via the name and not the ID. (Look closely my JS code)